# Geometry: Finding an angle of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Trapezoid $ABCD$ has right angles at $C$ and $D$, and $AD\gt BC$. Let $E$ and $F$ be the points on $AD$ and $AB$, respectively, such that $\angle BED$ and $\angle DFA$ are right angles. Let $G$ be the point of intersection of segments $BE$ and $DF$. If $\angle CED=58°$ and $\angle FDE=41°$, what is $\angle GAB$?

I already found that $ABE=41$, $FGB=EGD=BAE=49$, also $BAE=GAB+GAE$. I do not know what to do next. I already gave up. I looked at the answer at the back. The answer is $$17°$$

Can anyone help me how this answer was obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it without arguments involving trigonometric formulas. Draw diagonal segment $BD$. Look at triangle $ABD$. Segments $DF$ and $BE$ are altitudes in that triangle. Hence $G$ is the orthocenter. Thus $AG$ is the third altitude so $AG$ is orthogonal to $BD$. Therefore $\angle \, GAB = \angle \, GDB$. Now, since the quadrilateral $EBCD$ is a rectangle by assumption and construction, $$\angle \, BDE = \angle \, CED = 58^{\circ}.$$
From here, compute angle $\angle \, GDB$:
$$\angle \, GDB = \angle \, BDE - \angle \, FDE = 58^{\circ} - 41^{\circ} = 17^{\circ}.$$ This means that $\angle GAB = \angle GDB = 17^{\circ}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution is very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\angle CED=:\alpha$ and $\angle FDE=:\beta$. I claim that $\angle EGA=\alpha$.

[image]

*Proof.* Put $|DE|=:h$. Then $|BE|=|CD|=h\tan\alpha$, hence $|AE|=|BE|\tan\beta=h\tan\alpha\tan\beta$. On the other hand $|GE|=h\tan\beta$, so that $$\tan\angle EGA={|AE|\over |GE|}={h\tan\alpha\tan\beta\over h\tan\beta}=\tan\alpha\ .$$

(Maybe one could also argue using similar triangles.) The rest is easy.

Comment: I have a question. On what angles did you assign alpha and beta?

Comment: Nevermind. I already understand your solution. Very nice! Thank you very much. My only concern is how did you know that angle AGE is the angle that must be proven to be equal to alpha? Why could it not be others that is alpha?

Comment: I didn't know what had to be done. I just played with the problem until things clicked together.